# Register all dependency injection for all generic repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have too many DAL classes for whitch I need to register dependency injection for generic repository.

Class example:

```
[CollectionName("RenameMe")]
public class Test{

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ID { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("u")]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Generic class example:

```
public class GenericRepository<T, ID> : IGenericRepository<T, ID>
{
    public virtual T Save(T pobject)
    {
        _repository.Save(pobject);
        return pobject;
    }
}
```

When I register manually, I do like:

```
container.Register<IGenericRepository<DAL.Product, Guid>, GenericRepository<DAL.Product, Guid>>();
```

How i can make this automatically for each class in DAL namespace, ofc with CollectionName attribute:

```
private Container RegisterDAL(Container container)
{
    var classes = 
        from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.Namespace != null
        where t.IsClass
        where t.Namespace.StartsWith("DAL")
        where t.CustomAttributes
            .Any(i => i.GetType() == typeof(CollectionNameAttribute))
        select t;

    foreach (var dalClass in classes)
    {
        var idType = dalClass.CustomAttributes.First(
            p => p.AttributeType == typeof(BsonIdAttribute));

        // what to fill in in the question marks?
        container.Register<IGenericRepository<?, ?>, GenericRepository<?,?>>();
    }

    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an open generic mapping:

```
// using SimpleInjector.Extensions;

container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IGenericRepository<,>),
    typeof(GenericRepository<,>));
```

The `RegisterOpenGeneric` extension method is located in the `SimpleInjector.Extensions` namespace of the core library.

That will elegantly solve your problem.

Comment: Im using SimpleInjector and i cant find "RegisterOpenGeneric". Also i cant find "RegisterManyForOpenGeneric" as on http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Registration-Of-Open-Generic-Types 

Im using latest 2.3 version..

Comment: I'm sorry, `RegisterOpenGeneric` is an extension method in the `SimpleInjector.Extensions` namespace. You will have to include that namespace.

Comment: Oh, SimpleInjector.Extensions is additional nugget package. However, this solve my problem, it was very easy :)

Comment: No, it's not a package (any more). Since v2 the dll integrated in the core library.